Blueprintjs - Closing a Dialog when parent element unmounts
I'm rendering a grouped list. Each group has a blueprint Dialog component, which allows to move all items in that group to another group. In the dialog, there's an ok button. Clicking it should do the following:

Close the dialog.
Set parent group of all items in the group owning the dialog to the selected target group.

Problem: When all items are moved, the original group becomes empty and therefore ceases to exist and unmounts from DOM. Therefore the dialog does not remove "bp5-overlay-open" class from the body element and scrollbars remain hidden.
How do I ensure that the "bp5-overlay-open" is removed after the dialog is closed?
